# Issues with basic ruby if statement

Tags: arrays, ruby, if-statement

I'm trying to set up this code to check if a specific name exists within the array. In this instance, I want to see if Fred is on the list and if it isn't, put "Name wasn't on the list" underneath.

```
friends = Array["Kevin", "Karen", "Oscar"]

if (puts friends.include? "Fred" == false)
  puts ("Name wasn't on the list")
end
```

I'm new to ruby so I'm unsure if this is the correct method. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I meant "if statement "   :/

Comment: See [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Kernel.html#method-i-puts): `puts` **always** returns nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
friends = Array["Kevin", "Karen", "Oscar"]
```

This is not wrong, just overdone. `friends = ["Kevin", "Karen", "Oscar"]` is fine.

```
if (puts friends.include? "Fred" == false)
  puts ("Name wasnt on the list")
end
```

The `if (puts friends.include? "Fred" == false)` line looks innocent, but contains a surprising amount of mistakes, the most important being that `puts` always returns `nil`. This version works :

```
unless friends.include? "Fred" 
  puts "Name wasnt on the list"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `puts "Name wasn't on the list" unless friends.include? (name)`, here in a simple method:

```
def name_on_list(friends, name)
  puts "Name wasn't on the list" unless friends.include?(name)
end

friends = ["Kevin", "Karen", "Oscar"]
name_on_list(friends, "Fred")
```

You can remove the "Array" from the array declaration.

The function takes the friends and the name as arguments.

Within the function, I use the one-liner to print the text when the name is not included. I tend to use parenthesis to pass parameters but they are optional.